# What is the prime sign that a country is transitioning from a developing to a developed economy?

Tags: development

**Developed Economy** = low human capital flight, good infrastructure, low corruption, high per-capita income, dominated by hi-tech industry, high expenditure in R&D, high-quality higher education, high-quality health care, and so on.

**Developing Economy** = high human capital flight, bad infrastructure, high corruption, mediocre per-capita income, dominated by agriculture or service sector, not enough expenditure in R&D, low quality higher education, low life expectancy, and so on.

What is the first sign that a country is transitioning from a developing to a developed economy?

If we want to point to 'only one sign', what would that be?

And, Why?

Comment: This probably depends on your definition of "developing" and "developed" economies, so kindly add those. There aren't any universally accepted definitions.

Comment: Now you've provided those definitions, does it become apparent that seeking "only one sign" isn't practical, and that the transition would be marked by changes in *all* the criteria you've identified?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, I asked : which one is the **prime** sign and why?

Comment: That's what I was trying to say: there **isn't** a prime one. Because you've got complex definitions of developed/developing, then the transition will be complex too. **By your own definitions**, progress in one or two of the criteria will not be a real transition.

Comment: To put it another way: Why would we want to point to only one sign? In what respect would it be 'prime'? Would we not lose a lot of information by such a simplification?

Comment: @denesp, coz, I want to easily and quickly understand if a country is transitioning towards a developed status. There must be a factor that leads a developed economy.

Comment: There is no reason for a single factor to exist. There is also no single factor to forecast business success or next week's lottery numbers.

Comment: @anonymous  "easily and quickly understand"? Even if you identify one or a few factors, there's then the problem of how reliable the statistics are.  Eg Nigeria's stated GDP increased by 89% in one year (https://www.ft.com/content/70b594fe-bd94-11e3-a5ba-00144feabdc0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the '*first sign that a country is transitioning from a developing to a developed economy*', but I would look at the rates of output growth and study its acceleration.

In a layman's words, a transition from low to high income regime requires convergence to a high income teady state. This is only possible if the growth rate of aggregate output, underpinned by improvements in all aspects of the economy, has been consistently higher than that observed in high income (which you call developed) economies. Transition is complete (or the country achieves a 'developed' status) when the economy's growth rate reaches its long run steady state rate (typically low (<2% p.a.) positive growth rate).